# Use JS Variable in window.location

Tags: javascript, html, share, reddit

I'm trying to create a reddit share button, but I'm having trouble defining the window's location using variables. For example, this opens a share window on reddit, but it doesn't prefill the url field (leading me to believe the url parameter isn't being passed correctly):

```
<a href="//www.reddit.com/submit" onclick="shareOnReddit()">
    <img src="//www.redditstatic.com/spreddit7.gif" alt="submit to reddit" border="0"/> </a>
<script>
    function shareOnReddit() {
        var url = encodeURIComponent(window.location);
        alert(url);
        // shows correct url
        window.location = '//www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + url;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

But for some reason this (taken from the [reddit's documentation](https://www.reddit.com/buttons/)) does open a reddit share page with a prefilled url field:

```
<a href="//www.reddit.com/submit"
   onclick="window.location = '//www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location); return false"> <img
        src="//www.redditstatic.com/spreddit7.gif" alt="submit to reddit" border="0"/> </a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Can you describe what you have done in more detail?

Comment: why you say it is not working? Your code it is correct. A different way could be `document.location.href = '//www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + url;` but this does not change the result.

Comment: Sorry, guess I could have clarified more - the example from reddit will open a share window and prepopulate the url field with the current url. My modified example will open the share field, but it won't prefill the url as it should.

Answer (score -1):

After cleaning up the code, it looks like this:

```
<a onclick="shareOnReddit()">
    <img src="https://www.redditstatic.com/spreddit7.gif" alt="submit to reddit" border="0" />
</a>

<script>
    function shareOnReddit() {
        var url = encodeURIComponent(window.location);
        window.location = '//www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + url;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I recommend remove href="LINK" TAG, because the event is fire with the onClick="EVENT"